# Two fonts in the header using VBA

Tags: vba, fonts, ms-word

My Word document has about 260 sections with unique headers per section. Each header needs to have the left side in one text/font and the right side in another. It is for a series of bilingual books I'm making in different languages. Here is the code I've attempted to do, but it isn't changing the font for the second half of the header. The first 4 lines of code successfully change the header text, but the next part of code does not change the font. As an FYI, the part that says "Korean Chapter 1" will be in Korean and use Korean fonts.

```
Dim text1 As String
Dim text2 As String

With ActiveDocument.Sections(1)
'Changing the text
text1 = "English Chapter 1"
text2 = "Korean Chapter 1"
.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = text1 & vbTab & text2
'Changing the font
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(text1)
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Font.Name = "Batang"
End With

With ActiveDocument.Sections(2)
'Changing the text
text1 = "English Chapter 2"
text2 = "Korean Chapter 2"
.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = text1 & vbTab & text2
'Changing the font
SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(text1)
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Font.Name = "Batang"
End With

With ActiveDocument.Sections(3)... continuing until the last section
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By extending the Selection to the end of the Header you include the paragraph mark. Setting the Font then changes the font for the entire paragraph.

When coding in Word you should avoid using the Selection object as far as possible, especially when working with Headers and Footers. The code below should work for you.

```
Sub SetHeaderText()
    Dim text1 As String
    Dim text2 As String
    Dim rng As Range

    With ActiveDocument.Sections(1)
        'Changing the text
        text1 = "English Chapter 1"
        text2 = "Korean Chapter 1"
        Set rng = .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
        rng.Text = text1 & vbTab & text2
        rng.MoveStart Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(text1) + 1
        rng.Font.Name = "Batang"
    End With
End Sub
```

If the text that you are adding to the header really is just the chapter number then you could simplify your code and really speed things up by doing something like this:

```
Sub SetHeaderText()
    Dim text1 As String
    Dim text2 As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim sec As Section
    Dim num As Integer

    num = 1
    For Each sec In ActiveDocument.Sections
        'Changing the text
        text1 = "English Chapter " & num
        text2 = "Korean Chapter " & num
        Set rng = .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
        rng.Text = text1 & vbTab & text2
        rng.MoveStart Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=Len(text1) + 1
        rng.Font.Name = "AR Julian"
        num = num + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This was perfect. Thanks! I used both because I had books inside the book.